# Will a capacitive pen work with a moto G phone?

Tags: smartphones

I'm looking to buy a pen to be used with my moto G, and it has to have a fine point because I plan on writing with it.

So I know [these kinds](https://www.qualitylogoproducts.com/tradeshow-promotions/stick-stylus.htm?variant=BLANK&imageID=239801&feed=google&gclid=CMq2q_frjtECFUiRfgodL_kA7Q) of pen work with any capacitive screen and hence it works the moto G. But they're too thick.

So I'm planning on buying [one of these](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Precision-Fine-Round-Thin-Tip-Capacitive-Touch-Screen-Stylus-Pen-Pink/131826450280?_trksid=p2141725.c100338.m3726&_trkparms=aid%3D222007%26algo%3DSIC.MBE%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20150313114020%26meid%3D7a3d4e181fba4831ab6477bdcbbbfc1c%26pid%3D100338%26rk%3D1%26rkt%3D30%26sd%3D381667178163). The issue is that the website gives out a list of compatible devices with just a few devices on it (moto G not in it). But my question is: if this is a capacitive pen, shouldn't it work with all capacitive screen devices? Can I be sure that this pen will indeed work?

Also, is there a better option to get a pen that work the 1st gen Moto G phone?

Cheers

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because compatibility queries are not within this site's scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that stylus will work. It's capacitive and so is your device.

Sometimes, online listings like that will include a list of "compatible" products, either in the title or in the description. The list doesn't really mean anything, but if someone searches something like:

> `<popular device> stylus`

the listings with `<popular device>` are more likely to show up higher in the search results.